# Webpack - Build css not applied

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-loader, extract-text-plugin

I am new to ReactJS. I am trying to use scss in react using sass-loaders

My webpack config looks like this-

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname + 'react-js/src/');
var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'react-js/dist/');

const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: './react-js/src/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        publicPath: '/dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { 
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: 'css-loader',
                    publicPath: '/dist'
                })
            },
            { 
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: 'css-loader!sass-loader',
                    publicPath: '/dist'
                })
            },
            { 
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                  presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
    ]
}
```

All these configurations were from there respective documentations.

.

**When I run webpack-dev-server it shows following output-**

[image: WDS starting]

**This is the screen when I save a scss file -**
**Note** - I have removed the ExtractTextPlugin from my webpack config file.

[image: WDS on scss file save]

**Directory structure** -

[image]

I just don't realise how it's not imported to the rendered react app. I thought importing the scss file in index.jsx like shown below will make the css file it's dependency, but it doesn't work.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './app';

import style from '../../scss/main.scss';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />, 
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Why?

**Edited**

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "skippo-vendor-admin-webui",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./react-js/src/index.jsx",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack -d --progress --colors",
    "prod": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack -p --progress --colors",
    "watch": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack -d --progress --colors --watch",
    "start": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --hot --inline --contentBase './react-js/'"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "karma": "^1.6.0",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-sinon": "^1.0.5",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.3",
    "mocha": "^3.3.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "sinon": "^2.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.17.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.4",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `ExtractTextPlugin` should only be used for your production build, since it will create a separate compiled css file that can be served without any special treatment.

For development, you can use this rule instead:

```js
{
  test: /\.s?css$/,
  use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
}
```

Install the 3 loaders as a dev dependency if you don't have them.

Also you don't need to specify a name when you import a scss file, just import it.

```js
import  '../../scss/main.scss';
```

Comment: Thanks bro!! That works for webpack -d command. But it doesn't work for webpack-dev-server. Why is that? Are the config for WDSis wrong? I have updated the question with the package.json file. It includes the command for WDS. 

Thanks again

Comment: Can't you just use webpack with your `watch` script? You might have to add the `hot` option in your webpack config though.

Comment: Yes I can do that. But point is that I am learning stuff now.. So I don't wanna skip over **webpack-dev-server** and **ExtractTextPlugin** only because I can't figure out how to set it up for my environment. @Apercu

Comment: Yeah ok, what's the behavior? Any error or warning? Is the style processing logged in the console? Are you sure your config is picked up by wds? And I never said to skip the ExtractTextPlugin, just don't use it for dev.

Comment: Great!! See I have updated the question with 2 screenshots of WDS. I am confused that even when I have removed the ExtractTextPlugin it is still shown in WDS css build.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
import style from '../../scss/main.scss';
```

With

```
import  '../../scss/main.scss';
```